# How to parse JSON object into their designated types in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing, reactjs

When I make an API request, the API server returns me a JSON object. How do I parse the JSON object to their designated types in Javascript?

This is what is being returned to me:

```
{
    "student_name": "Joshua",
    "classes": [
        "A1",
        "A2",
        "A3",
    ]
    "food": {
        "size": "slice",
        "type": "pepperoni",
    }
}
```

So would like to parse the array, `classes`, the object, `food`, and the string `student_name`, and console log them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `JSON.parse()` to do it:

```
var myData = {
  "student_name": "Joshua",
  "classes": [
      "A1",
      "A2",
      "A3",
  ]
  "food": {
      "size": "slice",
      "type": "pepperoni",
  }
}

var myObject = JSON.parse(myData);

console.log(myObject.student_name); //Output: Joshua 
console.dir(myObject) //to see your object in console.
```

display a single element:

```
console.log(myData.classes[0]);
```

display all elements of an array:

```
var arr = myData.classes;

for(var i in arr) 
{
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

For more information:

- [About JSON.parse()](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)
- [JSON.Parse() Examples](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)

Comment: sorry but before I accept the answer and upvote, what's the reason for console.dir rather than .log? Also doing console.log(myData.classes) would log it as an array with those strings, correct? But how would I console log the first string, `A1`, in the classes array? And how would I dynamically console log the strings in the array? Because the size of array is not set.

Comment: `console.log` return strings and `console.dir` returns objects.

Comment: Just use console.log(myData.classess[0]); to get the first element of the classess array

Comment: And to get all elements of your array displayed, you should iterate the array. I can write you an example, how to do it

Answer (score 0):

JSON is the JavaScript Object Notation, which means JSON snippets already represent JavaScript objects. You just have to [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) them using:

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(json);
```

And then you can access:

```
var myArray = myObject.classes; //should give you an array
console.log(myArray[0]); //should print "A1"

var myFood = myObject.food //should give you a food object with size and type properties
console.log(myFood.size);  //should print "slice"
```